# PowerShell configure smtpserver

Tags: powershell, smtp, windows-server-2012-r2

In PowerShell how do you configure smtpserver:

```
ping "stmp.email.com" = “xxx.xx.xx.xxx”
$smtpServer = “xxx.xx.xx.xxx” or "stmp.email.com"????????
```

PS code:

```
$IPsmtp = 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx'
$PlainPassword = "adminpassword"
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Username = "MYSITE\Administrator"
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassword
$mailprops=@{
    Subject = 'This Subject'
    Body = 'The Body and the subBody'
    To = 'emailto@mail.com'
    From = 'emailfrom@email.com'
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.email.com'
}
Send-MailMessage $mailprops -Credential $Credentials
```

No matter if I use for SmtpServer: 'smtp.email.com' or $IPsmtp I still get the same result.

This ps code is missing the credentials for'smtp.email.com'.  It has a username and password associated with it but nowhere to enter it.

error code:

```
Send-MailMessage : The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ps\Email.ps1:14 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage $mailprops -Credential $Credentials
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Send-MailMessage], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Send-MailMessage : The email cannot be sent because no SMTP server was specified. You must specify an SMTP server by 
using either the SmtpServer parameter or the $PSEmailServer variable.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ps\Email.ps1:14 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage $mailprops -Credential $Credentials
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Comment: `$smtpServer =` Ip address or fqdn of your smtp server? Whichever works. Using a host name is usually smarter than using an ip address which can change over time.

Comment: Either one should work, however if it is a public server like gmail (smtp.gmail.com) you are probably better off using the server name.

Comment: You can also put that value into a preference variable called `$PSEmailServer`.  Then you don't even need to specify the -SmtpServer parameter.  The command will get the smtp server value from the preference variable.

Comment: You are intending to splat the parameters but that syntax is incorrect. Try: `Send-MailMessage @mailProps -Credential $Credentials`